# Google Sheets / Google Data Studio - RegEx

Tags: regex, google-sheets, looker-studio, re2

I got cells in a Google Sheet, which consist of some combined data to track workout progress. They look something like this:

> 80kg-3x5, 100kg-1x3

For a given exercise, i.e. hang snatch above, it means what actual work loads I did for that exercise on a given date, with weights and the related set x reps separated by commas. So for one exercise, I might have only one work load, or several (which are then comma separated). I have them in a single cell to keep the data tidy, and reduce time when entering the data after a workout.

Now to analyze the data, I need to somehow separate the comma separated values. An example using the sample cell data above, would be total volume for that exercise, with an expression like this:

```sql
Sum( (digit before 'kg') * (digit before 'x') * (digit after 'x') + Same expression before, if comma ',' exists after first expression (multiple loads for the exercise) )
```

It should be a trivial task, but I haven't touched the functions in google sheet or data studio that much, and I had a surprisingly difficult time figuring out a way to either loop through the content in a cell with appropriate regex, or other ways. I could do this easily in python and then any other visualization software, but the point for going this way using drive tools is that it saves a lot of time (if it works...). I can either implement it in google sheet, or in data studio as a new calculated column from the import, whichever makes it possible.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to write a custom function, something like this may do the trick (though it needs work for better error-handling)

```
function workoutProgress(string) {
  if (string == '' || string == null || string == undefined) { return 'error';}
  var stringArray = string.split(",");
  var sum = 0;
  var digitsArray, digitsProduct;
  if ( stringArray.length > 0) {
    for (var element in stringArray) {
      digitsArray = stringArray[element].match(/\d{1,}/g);
      digitsProduct = digitsArray.reduce(function(product, digit){ return product*digit;});
      sum += digitsProduct;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using the RegEx [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below where `Field` represents the respective field name; each row represents a single workload (for example `80kg-3x5`), thus the below accounts for 5 workloads (more can be added, for example a 6th could be added by copy-pasting the 5th line and incrementing he number in curly brackets by one - that is, changing `{4}` to `{5}`):

```sql
(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(\\d+)kg")AS NUMBER) * CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^\\d+kg-(\\d+)")AS NUMBER) * CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^\\d+kg-\\d+x(\\d+)")AS NUMBER)) + 
(NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){1}(\\d+)kg")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){1}\\d+kg-(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){1}\\d+kg-\\d+x(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0)) +
(NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){2}(\\d+)kg")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){2}\\d+kg-(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){2}\\d+kg-\\d+x(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0)) +
(NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){3}(\\d+)kg")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){3}\\d+kg-(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){3}\\d+kg-\\d+x(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0)) +
(NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){4}(\\d+)kg")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){4}\\d+kg-(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0) * NARY_MAX(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field,"^(?:\\d+kg-\\d+x\\d+,\\s){4}\\d+kg-\\d+x(\\d+)")AS NUMBER),0))
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report, Embedded Data Source](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/422a6eb5-a222-4346-b7f7-5b7dc3aa520e), Editable Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Scvym2XeCrLIszlvu6v_1aPGErgKoQH66aBZU-_INlk/edit?usp=sharing)) and a GIF to elaborate, so feel free to change the name of the field (at the Data Source) to adapt the field to the Calculated Field:

[image]